# Manual constructor chaining with dojo : argument issue

Tags: inheritance, constructor, dojo

I am trying to create a class inheriting one class.

In this class I want to create 2 objects which will be passed to the constructor of the parent class.

To do this, I have to use manual constructor chaining and call 'inherited' (see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/declare.html#manual-constructor-chaining)

My issue is that I can't correctly pass parameters to the inherited method. When I use the followind code:

```
   define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Cache", "dojo/store/Observable"],

   function(declare, JsonRest, Memory, Cache, Observable)
   {
      var userStore;
      return declare("app.UserStore", [Cache],
         {
            "-chains-":
            {
               constructor: "manual"
            },
            constructor: function()
            {
               this.masterStore = new JsonRest({
                  target: "/User/json",
                  idProperty: "name"
               });

               this.cacheStore = new Memory({ idProperty: "name" });

               this.inherited([this.masterStore, this.cacheStore]);
            }
         });
   });
```

I get an arg.callee undefined in declare.js.

When I pass 'arguments' as a parameter to inherited, then callee is defined. Is it possible to add more arguments dynamically to the arguments object?

If not how may I call the parent with dynamically created objects in this constructor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `this.inherited` must always be `arguments`.  This is so `dojo.declare` can figure out the superclass method based on `arguments.callee`. Given that this is the case, if you want to send different arguments to the superclass method then you should have an array as the 2nd argument to `this.inherited`.  I haven't confirmed that this works for constructors but I would try the following:

```
this.inherited(arguments, [this.masterStore, this.cacheStore]);
```

I'm curious to find out if it works.

Comment: thanks! That's what I did, reading the doc further. So it fixes the issue of the call to the parent constructor. The issue now is that when I create an object with this, I have no access to the Cache functions (get, query, ...). So there is still something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Dojo[1] allow you to pass a reference to the currently executing function as the first argument to `this.inherited`, to enable its use in strict mode.

As a side-effect, the second argument can indeed be an array (even from non-strict code):

```
constructor: function fn() {
    //...

    this.inherited(fn, [this.masterStore, this.cacheStore]);
}
```

[1] 1.12 or later, if I'm not mistaken.